# Placing PHP inside SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use php to determine which table my information is coming from but don't know how to place the PHP correctly into the statement.

Say I have the tables:

```
page1_articles
page2_articles
page3_articles
```

And I give the page an ID of `$page = "page1"` or `$page = "page2"` or `$page = "page3"`

How can I use this in my `SELECT` statement:

```
$get_articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM $page_articles ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$get_articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $page . "_articles ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5";
```

With this you concat $page which could be `page1` or `page2` or `page3` with the string _articles

Edit after comment:

Escape your variable if you didn't do that already! with this:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($page);
```

Comment: And don't forget to sanitize your variables, especially if you're not using PDO (which you totally should).

Comment: @devJunk your right! But i hope he already escaped the variables.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I don't think I need to escape anything in this case as there is no other user input, I determine what $page is at the top of the php page

Comment: @user3177012 if your 1000% sure that no user can change the value you don't have to escape it, but i would do it! just to be sure! Or you can change your querys to PDO.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yeah I'm sure but I'll do it anyway - I like working in this code ;-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php mysql_real_escape_string will soon be deprecated, it will eventually stop working. It should not advisable for anyone to use mysql_query functions any more.

Answer (score 0):

this will work
$get_articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$page_articles." ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5";

this code will work better
$get_articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$page_articles."` ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5";

this code is be best 
$get_articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$page_articles}` ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5";